# Dynamic transpose of rows to columns in sql, no need to bring column/row value as header

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in SQL, but don't want to achieve this using code as I researched that it can be achieved through SQL.

Query

```
select 
    c.CLAIM_ID,
    e.CODE,
    e.DX_TYPE
from 
    claim_sub c,
    diagnosis_sub e
where 
    c.uid = e.DIAG_CLAIM_UID and
    --e.uid = f.DXINFO_DIAG_UID and
    c.claim_id in( 'IP0000013119','IP0000013124')
```

Current output:

```
CLAIM_ID        DX_TYPE     CODE
-------------------------------------
IP0000013119    PRINCIPAL   M62.82
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   E55.9
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   M79.652
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   M79.651
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   M51.37
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   R20.0
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   R94.4
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   R79.89
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   R73.09
IP0000013124    PRINCIPAL   K52.9
IP0000013119    SECONDARY   E86.0
IP0000013124    SECONDARY   R10.9
IP0000013124    SECONDARY   R11.10
IP0000013124    SECONDARY   R63.8
IP0000013124    SECONDARY   R79.89
```

Desired output:

```
Claim_ID    DX_TYPE1    CODE1   DX_TYPE2    CODE2   DX_TYPE3    CODE3   DX_TYPE4    CODE4   DX_TYPE5    CODE5   DX_TYPE6    CODE6   DX_TYPE7    CODE7   DX_TYPE8    CODE8   DX_TYPE9    CODE9
IP0000013119    PRINCIPAL   M62.82  SECONDARY   E55.9   SECONDARY   M79.652 SECONDARY   M79.651 SECONDARY   M51.37  SECONDARY   R20.0   SECONDARY   R94.4   SECONDARY   R79.89  SECONDARY   R73.09
IP0000013124    PRINCIPAL   K52.9   SECONDARY   E86.0   SECONDARY   R10.9   SECONDARY   R11.10  SECONDARY   R63.8   SECONDARY   R79.89
```

Comment: hint : pivoting or use case expression if u have fix col lenght.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't put in the extra effort to provide us with ddl for the tables used plus a set of test data in it, I can't give you the answer to your question in sql code. I can however give you a link to an excellent article on the topic of cross tabs and pivots written Jeff Moden, so you can research and understand the topic completely: [Part 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/) & [Part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/).